# Framework Bottle and OSError

Tags: python, json, bottle

I am trying to make a very simple thing with Bottle. I would like to take my .json file and convert it to the HTML table.

There are my files:

**main.py**

```
from bottle import route, run, template, error

HOST = '192.168.47.101'

with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

@route('/main_page')
def serve_homepage():
    return template('disp_table', rows = data)

@error(404)
def error404(error):
    return 'There is nothing... :('

run(host=HOST, port=8080)
```

**disp_table.tpl**

```
%# disp_table.tpl
<table border="1">
<tr>
%for row in rows:
<th>{{row}}</th>
%end
</table>
```

**data.json**

```
{
'First row' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
'Second row': [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
}
```

I suspect to see something like this:

```
---------------------------------------------
|First row  | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9             |
---------------------------------------------
|Second row | 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 |
---------------------------------------------
```

But I have this error after command `python3 main.py`:

```
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I use this:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Python 3.8.5
- Bottle 0.12.19

What is wrong with my code? How can I fix it?

Comment: Either you host IP is not assigned to the computer or the port is already bound to a process.

Comment: Thank you! That have solved my problem (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that your server process couldn't bind to the port that you specified (8080). You can either (1) try a different port, e.g.

```
run(host=HOST, port=8580)
```

or (2) find out which process is already using port 8080 and shut that down.